# What is a file?

Tags: files, disk

I thought that the `file` is a reserved place on disk and it is a Record collection

but i found that it is a wrong definition because the empty file capacity is `0kb` 
so it can't be a reserved place on disk ,

```
mostafa@jamareh:~$ cd Desktop/
mostafa@jamareh:~/Desktop$ touch test
mostafa@jamareh:~/Desktop$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mostafa mostafa 0 Feb 28 16:55 test
```

as you see in this example the os shows us there is a file and the capacity is `0kb` , so i want to know why the capacity is `0kb` and where is test file ?

what is a file on the `os` level ?

actually i want to know the definition of file in the `operating system` level

Comment: I do not understand the logic of your conclusion. I guess you have to improve your wording.

Comment: what is a file, at what level ? on file system level ? on OS level ? on a specific file system ? this is very broad.

Comment: @MostafaJamareh please complete your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Are you asking how a file is described to the operating system?  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms

Comment: You maybe confused with file itself and file's metadata. Each file has metadata related to it, e.g. file size, file name, file permission etc. But the file itself can be empty as in your case.

Comment: finally someone answered to this question . thank you @yegle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file is an identifier for accessing data. The amount of data can be zero and it can usually change over time as can the data itself. To the file belongs some meta data (specific to the file system type and configuration being used) like access rights and timestamps for different types of accesses.

Comment: thank you Hauke , where is my test file that i create it on the question ?

Comment: @MostafaJamareh I don't understand the question.

Comment: it is easy , i created a file using `touch` command , and i want to know where is this file ? if it is on hard disk why the capacity is `0kb`?

Comment: @MostafaJamareh Strange question. That depends on the argument of `touch`, especially which volume it points to. Most probably it's on a hard disk. The file size is zero because `touch` does not change the file size. Thus if called for a non-existing file the file is created with size zero.

Comment: so you mean it is a reserved place on the hard disk that this space that belongs to that file can increase when we write something in that file , so the capacity of files must not be `0kb` with your definition because you say it is a reserved place ,

Comment: You open a bank account. Where is it ? John: "I thought a bank account held money", Mary: "Well you haven't put any money in there yet.". It's a convenient concept, for you to use with your bank.

Comment: but bank has the place to store your account , where is this place on the os that shows us there is a empty file on Desktop,

Comment: @MostafaJamareh The term "capacity" it not used with single files. Files have a size. Even files with size zero cover some space on a volume (size of the directory entry plus maybe extended attributes; one inode). All relevant tools (e.g. `ls`, `du`) refer to the "official size" and/or to the amount of used blocks. There is no command to tell you how much space the file administration consumes. The available file system size which `df` shows you is smaller than the block device size. The data you are talking about is "hidden" in this size difference.

Comment: @Mostafa Jamareh No it hasn't, the bank *keeps track* of the money in your account in it's accounting system. OS relies on the file system to do this in the part of file system you do not see, the i-Node